# Default Role Provider could not be found only when browse to subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, roleprovider

On WinHost I have a working domain. Today I added a a subdomain to it, configured IIS and add rules to redirect the request to subd.domain.com/subd. both the domain and the subdomain are mvc3 applications both have web.config. my Domain uses mycustomMembershipProvider and mycustomROleprovider. but the subdomain uses AspnetSqlMembershipProvider. still the domain is working but when I browse to subd.Mydomian.com it generates "Default Role Provider could not be found." and it points to the web.config of the domain and myCustomRoleProvider. thanks for your advice.

Comment: I solved it by adding  enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" to the RoleManager element of the Web.Config file of the subdomain.